# Copying Data from a Row in One Worksheet to another Worksheet Using MACRO

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

I am working on a spreadsheet that needs to copy information generated on one worksheet to another spreadsheet for printing purposes. The information on the primary spreadsheet (data sheet) is generated through two drop-down lists containing the height and width of the object. I would like to be able copy this information generated on the data sheet onto the print sheet and continue this process by copying a new height-width combo onto a new row on the print sheet. The macro I have so far is giving me an error, and I was wondering if there is any solution for this problem

```
Sub copyRow()
Dim wsd1 As Worksheet
Dim wsd2 As Worksheet
Dim wsp As Worksheet
Dim Row1 As Long

' define which worksheet to work on, i.e. replace Sheet1 with the name of your sheet
Set wsd1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Data Sheet").Range("B11:H11")
Set wsd2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Data Sheet").Range("M11:R11")
Set wsp = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Print Sheet")

' determine the last row with content in column A and add one
Row1 = Worksheets("Print Sheet").Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row + 1

' copy data from data sheet to print sheet
wsd1.Copy wsp.Range("C" & Row1)


End Sub
```

Thanks for any help!

Michael

Comment: What is the error it is giving you?

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim wsd1 As Worksheet
[ ... ]
Set wsd1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Data Sheet").Range("B11:H11")
```

You are trying to assign a Range to a Worksheet object.

```
Dim wsd1 As Range
[ ... ]
Set wsd1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Data Sheet").Range("B11:H11")
```